# Xamarin set IsVisible of a button inside a Grid based on multiple bound properties in the same Grid.Row without editing the original model

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a button that can appear in each row of a grid.
I need to hide the button if any bound property in the "row" is null.
This is using the MVVM pattern so that the ViewModel has an ObservableCollection.

Very simplified example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int? Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int? Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<TestClass> _TestClasses;
    public ObservableCollection<TestClass> TestClasses
    {
        get { return _TestClasses; }
        set { _TestClasses = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TestClasses)); }
    }

    // LOAD TEST DATA IN CONSTRUCTOR
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        var testClasses = new List<TestClass>();
        testClasses.Add(new TestClass { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = 1 };
        testClasses.Add(new TestClass { Prop1 = 2, Prop2 = null };
        testClasses.Add(new TestClass { Prop1 = null, Prop2 = 2 };

        TestClasses = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>(testClasses);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class NullBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? false : true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The following XAML will hide the button when "Prop1" is null BUT I need to hide the button if "EITHER" Prop1 or Prop2 is NULL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TestProject.Converters"
             x:Class="TestProject">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:NullBooleanConverter x:Key="NullBooleanConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TestClasses}" 
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  HasUnevenRows="True" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Grid>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>                                    
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Prop2}"/>                                    
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
                                    <Button Text="Do Something" 
                                            IsVisible="{Binding Path=Prop1, Converter={StaticResource NullBooleanConverter}}" />
                                </StackLayout>

                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**UPDATE 1**
I can't edit the original model because it is in a shared library that is used among several other projects.
I could create a partial class of the model and but seems overly complicated in that in all our other projects this is easily achievable in the UI or using a IMultiValueConverter but this is not supported in Xamarin.

**UPDATE 2**
I have found a "hack" way of doing this inside the NullBooleanConverter.

```
public class NullBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is TestClass)
        {
            TestClass testClass = (TestClass)value;

            if (testClass.Prop1 == null || testClass.Prop2 == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also binding the property **IsVisible** to ViewModel

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
   <Button Text="Do Something" 
           IsVisible="{Binding isVisible}" />
</StackLayout>
```

> in Model

```
public class TestClass
{
  public string? Prop1 { get; set; }
  public string? Prop2 { get; set; }      
  public bool isVisible { get; private set; }

  public TestClass(string? p1,string?p2)
  {
      if(p1==null||p2==null)
      {
        isVisible = false;
      }
      else
      {
        isVisible = true;
      }
  }

}
```

> And in ViewModel

```
var testClasses = new List<TestClass>();
testClasses.Add(new TestClass("1","1") );
testClasses.Add(new TestClass(null,"2") );
testClasses.Add(new TestClass("1",null));
TestClasses = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>(testClasses);
```

In addition,the type of text is string not int .

**Update:**

I think your way is wisely (not a hack way) . You just need to set

```
<Button Text="Do Something" IsVisible="{Binding , Converter={StaticResource NullBooleanConverter}}" />
```

Otherwise, you can also create a subclass of **Button** and define two **BindableProperties** , then binding them to **Prop1** and **Prop2** . It will be complex which I don't suggest you to choose it .

Comment: I agree that editing my "Model" is one way to do this BUT the example I supplied is very over simplified. In my work environment, the models are in an external library that is shared among Web, Windows, WPF, and Xamarin projects and I am not allowed to edit the original model. I should have specified that in the title / question. I do thank you for the help. This was achievable in WPF by using the IMultiValueConverter but I can't see to find a similar way to do this in Xamarin.

Comment: You can do this in your viewmodel

Comment: Please forgive me for sounding stupid but how can I do this in the ViewModel? My TestClasses is a collection that is bound to a grid so I am not sure how to do this without building another model that extends the current TestClass. I did find a "hack" way of doing this that I am going to list above but if you have some other way, I would really like to learn that way.

Comment: Building another model that extends the current TestClass is a good way. Why don't you do it?

Comment: I was trying not to extend the models because the models are poco passed to an OData service and we are trying to keep them as clean as possible. Basically we pull down a json object from the OData service, edit it, and then post it back to the service. If the model does not match the one on the service then the service will reject the json. Guess we can create local models and then use a mapper but this all seems overkill just to set "visible" on a button based on two fields in the model.